# How to reverse engineer Postgres 9.0 database

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, .net-6.0, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application uses EF Core with Npgsql.

Reverse engineering Postgres 9.0 database using

```
scaffolder.ScaffoldModel(connectionString.ToString(), dbOpts, modelOpts, codeGenOpts);
```

Throws exception

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column "enumsortorder" does not exist

at sql

```
SELECT
  nspname,
  typname,
  array_agg(enumlabel ORDER BY enumsortorder) AS labels
FROM pg_enum
JOIN pg_type ON pg_type.oid = enumtypid
JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_type.typnamespace
GROUP BY nspname, typname
```

with stack trace

> at
> Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong|213_0(NpgsqlConnector
> connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode,
> Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean
> async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean
> async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.GetEnums(NpgsqlConnection
> connection, DatabaseModel databaseModel)    at
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection
> dbConnection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Scaffolding.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String
> connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String
> connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions,
> ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions
> codeOptions)

How to reverse engineer Postgres 9.0 database in .NET6 ? Enum data types are almost not used.

Comment: I would suggest backup database and restore on higher Postgres version instance and then Scaffold. Don't think that Npgsql will do that shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this for 6.0.2, see https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2160.

It would be better if you didn't cross-post the same question on both github and stackoverflow - it mainly creates more work answering in both places. If something looks like an Npgsql bug, and issue should be enough, otherwise stackoverflow is good for usage questions etc.